# Boolean check if a specific element is part of a filtered list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I'm working with Scheme and want to do some simple programs. I created one in which the multiples of five are filtered out of a list. Now I want to write a boolean function in which it will tell me if a specific element is part of the filtered list! So if I write "8" it will say false, but "40" would say true. Thanks!

```
(define (multiple-of-5 some-integer)
  (equal? (remainder some-integer 5) 0))

(filter multiple-of-5 '(2 5 8 20 25 27 32 40))
```

output so far:

```
(5 20 25 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `contains?` recursive function which travels the list and checks if the input number is equal to the current list element. The condition to stop is if the list is empty or if it contains the number. Pretty self-explanatory.

```
(define (contains? l i)
  (if (null? l) #f
      (or (equal? (car l) i) (contains? (cdr l) i))))

(contains? (filter multiple-of-5 '(2 5 8 20 25 27 32 40)) 8)  ; #f
(contains? (filter multiple-of-5 '(2 5 8 20 25 27 32 40)) 40) ; #t
```

Comment: Don't use `eq?` to compare numbers or anything but symbols and characters. The same value is not guaranteed to be true. Eg. `(eq? 10 10) ; ==> #f` (or `#t`) and it can switch within the same implementation based on optimization settings. In this case when you making general comparison on any type `equal?` is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

How you produced the list `(5 20 25 40)` is irrelevant. Thus all your code is irrelevant to this question. Basically you want this:

```
(define some-list '(5 20 25 40)) ; doesn't matter how this came about
(find (lambda (e) (= e 8)) some-list) ; ==> #f
(find (lambda (e) (= e 40)) some-list) ; ==> 40 (thruthy)
```

Now `find` is defined in the SRFI-1 List library and it is voted into R7RS Large. I imagine you could make an abstraction more useful for your case like `(exists? 40 some-list)` that uses `find` or you can roll your own like in Torbio's answer.